# passing value from asp.net page to t4 template

Tags: c#, asp.net, t4

I wish to pass a string value from my asp.net web page to a t4 runtime template. The runtime template includes some more template files. ie.

My runtime template is say, **runTym.tt**

This runTym.tt inclues two t4 templates ie: **t1.tt** and **t2.tt**

The runTym.tt code is like this:

```
<#@ template language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ include file="t1.tt" #> 
<#@ include file="t2.tt" #>
```

I want to pass a value to **t1.tt** file. But, I am accessing the runTym.tt file from the asp.net web page.

```
runTym runT = new runTym();
string val= runT.TransformText();
```

Is there any way to pass parameter value to **t1.tt** through **runTym.tt** ?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the class the runtime template is generating and add a second partial of that class in your own file.  Add a public property in that partial, and then just set the property after `new`ing up the runtime template and before you call `TransformText()`.

If you prefer to keep things all in just one file, then add the property in a class feature block at the end of your template instead, using `<#+ #>` as delimiters.